# how to match those useragent strings in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a list of useragent that I need to filter on. but I failed to do this.

For example, there are 5 useragent in the below. The name of the table is temp and the column name is useragent. I want to return the first 3 in postgresql.

```
"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/603.3.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14G60 Safari/602.1"

"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/602.1.50 (KHTML, like Gecko) GSA/33.0.164895372 Mobile/14G60 Safari/602.1"

"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/603.3.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14G60 Safari/602.1"

"POF 6.21.912; (iPhone8,2; iOS 10.3.3; en_US; g=ON; p=ON; r=WiFi) 0ADC1470-4814-4100-83A6-D9D4843F2DFA;"

"POF 6.21.912; (iPhone9,2; iOS 10.3.3; en_US; g=ON; p=ON; r=WiFi) D7CBD4C8-3482-4226-93DB-B8894AFFD087;"
```

Here is the code I am trying:

```
select useragent from temp where useragent  like `'^Mozilla/\\d\\.\\d\\s\\(iPhone*'`
```

it returns nothing. Does anyone can help me fix the grammar of this line?

Comment: Why would it return anything? It sounds ike you are trying to use PCRE patterns in a LIKE expression (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE). You will find working with computer systems much easier if you take the time to get a basic level of familiarity with the documentation first.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `like`, `like` can only check one string such as '%abc%' wether is contained by another such as 'kkabchh', and would not applicable to regular expressions.You should use `~` in `PostgreSQL`, as below:

```
postgres=# select 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/603.3.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14G60 Safari/602.1' ~ 'Mozilla.*iPhone.*' as bool;
 bool 
------
 t
(1 row)

postgres=# select useragent from temp where useragent ~ 'Mozilla.*iPhone.*';
                                                                   useragent                                                                    
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/603.3.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14G60 Safari/602.1
 Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/602.1.50 (KHTML, like Gecko) GSA/33.0.164895372 Mobile/14G60 Safari/602.1
 Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/603.3.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14G60 Safari/602.1
(3 rows)
```